# modified .htaccess file doesn't block bad user agents with RewriteCond

Tags: security, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, user-agent

I found this modified .htaccess settings for extra security, but it doesn't seem to work. Here it is :

```
# Apache configuration file
# httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/quickreference.html

# Techniques in here adapted from all over, 
#   including Kroc Camen: camendesign.com/.htaccess

ServerSignature Off

# you probably want www.example.com to forward to example.com -- shorter URLs are sexier.
#   no-www.org/faq.php?q=class_b
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  ^(HEAD|TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}     ^.*(\\r|\\n|%0A|%0D).* [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}    ^(.*)(<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}     ^.*(<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}     ^/(,|;|:|<|>|”>|”<|/|\\\.\.\\).{0,9999}.* [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(java|curl|wget).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(winhttp|HTTrack|clshttp|archiver|loader|email|harvest|extract|grab|miner).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(libwww-perl|curl|wget|python|nikto|scan).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    ^.*(;|<|>|’|”|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update|md5|benchmark).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    ^.*(localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    ^.*\.[A-Za-z0-9].* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    ^.*(<|>|’|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC]


########## Begin – Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
## Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
########### End – Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

########## Block bad user agents
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
RewriteRule .* - [F]


# Force the latest IE version, in various cases when it may fall back to IE7 mode
#  github.com/rails/rails/commit/123eb25#commitcomment-118920
# Use ChromeFrame if it's installed for a better experience for the poor IE folk
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    BrowserMatch MSIE ie
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>


# hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/
# Disabled. Uncomment to serve cross-domain ajax requests
#<IfModule mod_headers.c>
#  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
#</IfModule>




# allow access from all domains for webfonts
# alternatively you could only whitelist
#   your subdomains like "sub.domain.com"

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>


# video
AddType video/ogg  ogg ogv
AddType video/mp4  mp4
AddType video/webm webm

# Proper svg serving. Required for svg webfonts on iPad
#   twitter.com/FontSquirrel/status/14855840545
AddType image/svg+xml                 svg svgz 

# webfonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
AddType font/ttf                      ttf
AddType font/otf                      otf
AddType font/x-woff                   woff

AddType text/cache-manifest           manifest

# allow concatenation from within specific js and css files 

# e.g. Inside of script.combined.js you could have
#   <!--#include file="jquery-1.4.2.js" -->
#   <!--#include file="jquery.idletimer.js" -->
# and they would be included into this single file

# this is not in use in the boilerplate as it stands. you may
#   choose to name your files in this way for this advantage
#   or concatenate and minify them manually.
# Disabled by default.

# <FilesMatch "\.combined\.(js|css)$">
#         Options +IncludesNOEXEC
#         SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
# </FilesMatch>


# gzip compression.
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

# html, xml, css, and js:
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript text/javascript application/javascript application/json 

# webfonts and svg:
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg)$" >
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>


# these are pretty far-future expires headers
# they assume you control versioning with cachebusting query params like
#   <script src="application.js?20100608">
# additionally, consider that outdated proxies may miscache 
#   www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/

# if you don't use filenames to version, lower the css and js to something like
#   "access plus 1 week" or so

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  Header set cache-control: public
  ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
  ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

# cache.manifest needs re-reqeusts in FF 3.6 (thx Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"

# your document html 
  ExpiresByType text/html                  "access"

# rss feed
  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"

# favicon (cannot be renamed)
  ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon  "access plus 1 week" 

# media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"

# webfonts
  ExpiresByType font/ttf                  "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/woff                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"

# css and javascript
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript           "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>




# Since we're sending far-future expires, we don't need ETags for
# static content.
#   developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
FileETag None


# Allow cookies to be set from iframes (for IE only)
# If needed, uncomment and specify a path or regex in the Location directive

# <IfModule mod_headers.c>
#   <Location />
#     Header set P3P "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\""
#   </Location>
# </IfModule>

# without -MultiViews, Apache will give a 404 for a rewrite if a folder of the same name does not exist (e.g. “/blog/hello”)
#   webmasterworld.com/apache/3808792.htm
Options -MultiViews 
# -Indexes will have Apache block users from browsing folders without a default document
Options -Indexes

# custom 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 /intro.php

# use utf-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
# force utf-8 for a number of file formats
AddCharset utf-8 .html .css .js .xml .json .rss .php
```

I used

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

And switched my user agent so it displays `ChinaClaw`, a bad user agent. I thought I would get a error messages and not be able to display the page?

Comment: In lieu of giving a full answer, I would suggest stripping down the `.htaccess` file into the minimum bit that doesn't do what you want. It makes it a lot easier for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the way you combine the conditions in `RewriteCond`. Implicitly consecutive conditions are combined with logical AND and the *OR* flag turns that combination into a logical OR combination.